# Obtener valores de inputs NO VACIOS, me salen vacíos

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp, vbscript

Los inputs de este pequeño formulario me salen vacíos al obtener su valor con javascript y no sé el porqué.

Código del Formulario

```
<!--#INCLUDE FILE="class/clsData.asp" -->
```

```
            <!--#INCLUDE FILE="menu.asp" -->
            <div class="span12" id="content">

                <div class="row-fluid">
                        <!-- block -->
                        <div class="block">
                            <div class="navbar navbar-inner block-header">
                                <div class="muted pull-left">Paso 1. Ingresar Nombre de Cliente y DNI</div>
                            </div>
                 <div class="modal-body" style="height: 200px">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <form class="form-horizontal" id="FormAddCliente" method="post">                    
                    <fieldset>
                        
                        <div class="control-group" >
                            <label class="control-label" for="edit_nombre">Nombre:</label>
                            <div class="controls" >
                                <input id="input_nombre" name="nombre" type="text" value="">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div><br></div>

                        <div class="control-group">
                            <label class="control-label" for="add_dni">DNI:</label>
                            <div class="controls">
                                <input id="input_dni" name="numero" type="text">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                         <div class="control-group">
                            <div class="controls">
                                <button type="button" class="pull-center btn btn-info" id="BtnSiguiente">Siguiente</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        
                      </fieldset>
                      </form>
                      </div>
                      </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Y AQUI EN EL JAVASCRIPT QUIERO OBTENER LO QUE DIGITO EN AMBOS INPUT PERO ME SALEN VACIOS, PARA LUEGO USARLOS EN EL AJAX DE ABAJO. ESE ES EL PROBLEMA ( LA OBTENCION DE LOS VALORES)

```
<script >

$(function() {

    var Nombre= $("#input_nombre").val();
    var dni= $("#input_dni").val();

    var insertCliente = function(Nombre,dni){
        $.ajax({
                url:  window.location.pathname.slice(0,window.location.pathname.lastIndexOf("/"))+'/ajax_venta.asp',
                type : "POST",
                data :{NFUNC:"3",NOMBRE : Nombre,DNI: dni},
                datatype : "json",                  
                success: function(respuesta) {
                    $toast = toastr["success"]("Cliente agregado.", "¡CORRECTO!");
                },
                error: function(E) {
                    $toast = toastr["error"]("Algo salio mal", "¡ERROR!");
                }
            });
    };

    $("#BtnSiguiente").click(function(){
        alert(Nombre);
        alert(dni);

            //insertCliente(Nombre,dni);
          
        });
});
```

Comment: Debes leer los valores de tus elementos input dentro de la función que maneja el clic al botón. Actualmente sólo los lees al cargar el documento y por ende están vacíos. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras Gracias! funcionó